# How to disable JavaScript in media query

Tags: javascript, media

I want to dissable javascripts in media query.

```
@media only screen
 (max-device-width : 568px) {
.sidebar { display: none; } 
  #navmenu {  margin-top:0px; width:auto; padding:10px; margin-left:15%;}
.content {width:auto; height:auto; margin-left:0; margin-top:3%;}
.contentsing{position:relative; width:100%; height:auto; margin-left:0%; margin-top:-150px;}


}
```

That is mu code, now i want to add something that will disable scripts.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Do you want to disable your own scripts?

Comment: Yes.. here is link [link]http://stefanvblog.com/category/news/

Now i want to disable that script with menu on mobile device.

Comment: Well CSS can not disable JavaScript so you need to make your JavaScript detect that state.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could wrap your script in an if statement that checks how wide the screen is like this:

```
if(window.innerWidth > 568){
    ...execute script
}
```

However, that will only execute once, so what if you resize your browser window? You could have an event listener that executes your script whenever you resize the browser.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    if(window.innerWidth > 568){
        ...execute script
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use jQuery - this code will help you

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width()>992){
        ...execute script
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this would work better....

```
if ($(window).width()>568){
    ...execute script
}
```