# How to disable jQuery plugin on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, media

I'm trying to implement the window resize event listener so that the jScroll jQuery plugin I'm using doesn't fire on smaller screens where the scrolling of certain items is causing problems.

By putting together a mix of stuff i've read here this is what i've come up with:

```
<script>    
    $(window).resize(function() {
        windowWidth = $(this).width();
        if (.windowWidth() > 602) {
            $(".sectionTitle").jScroll({speed : "slow",top : 50});
});

</script>
```

[How to disable JavaScript in media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659338/how-to-disable-javascript-in-media-query/) was my main source of help but still haven't got it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

RE the comments:
this is what I get in the console:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . (index):113
2
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (index):1
GET http://ghost-mirror.org/notify_act.php net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED jquery.js:5

When i dont wrap the jscroll code in the resize function, .sectionTitle follows the users scrolling in the window like a fixed element until it reaches the end of its container.

I updated the code like entiendo stated:

```
<script>    
$(window).resize(function() {
    var windowWidth = $(this).width();
    if(windowWidth > 602) {
        $(".sectionTitle").jScroll({speed : "slow",top : 50});
        }
  });
</script>
```

If I could just get the plugin to run by default on window widths more than 602px and disabled by default on windows less than 602 i would be super grateful. (At the moment it only runs when I resize the window, so If I load up the page but dont change the size then the script doesnt run).

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? Are you getting any JS errors in your console? For example, I can clearly see a syntax error in your code - you'll need to fix this before continuing...

Comment: Your updated code still has two syntax errors. Both contained within `if (.windowWidth() > 602) {`

Comment: "not working" is not a description of the problem...Please add all the relevant info - are there any more errors being reported?

Comment: First, figure out how to disable jScroll. don't worry about the resize event until you can disable jScroll.

Comment: @KevinB - but even before that, the OP needs to fix all of the syntax issues...

Comment: @Lix he already has. see comments on entiendo's answer. He does however still need to fix them in his question.

Comment: @KevinB - without knowing that the OP is able to identify syntax errors I am not making any assumptions...

Answer (score 0):

So, here's a suggestion:

HTML:

```
 <div id="container">
     <div class="scroll">
     <h3>Page 1</h3>
     <p>Page 1 of jScroll Example - jQuery Infinite Scrolling Plugin
     This is the content of page 1 in the jScroll example. Scroll to the bottom of this box to load the next set of content.

     This is example text for the jScroll demonstration. jScroll is a jQuery plugin for infinite scrolling, endless scrolling, lazy loading, auto-paging, or whatever you may call it.

     With jScroll, you can initialize the scroller on an element with a fixed height and overflow setting of "auto" or "scroll," or it can be set on a standard block-level element within the document and the scrolling will be initialized based on the brower window's scroll position.

     jScroll is open-source and can be downloaded from my GitHub repository at github.com/pklauzinski/jscroll. </p>
     <a href="example-page2.html">next page</a>
     </div>
 </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var origElement = $('.scroll').clone(); //we're cloning the original element and will use that to replace the content of the div "container" whenever the window size is less than 602px

if($(window).width() > 602){
    $('.scroll').jscroll();
    }

$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() < 602){
        alert($(window).width());
       $('.scroll').remove();
       $('#container').html(origElement);
       }
    else{
         $('.scroll').jscroll();
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6YXFu/3/

Comment: because fixing syntax errors will solve the problem he's asking about.

Comment: fantastic! this worked, thank you so much. Only problem now is that the jScroll will only fire when i resize the window, ie. if i just load up the page without resizing the code wont run. Is there a way I can make it run by default and then only disable if the window is detected at less than 602px? cheers dude

Comment: It obviously hasn't. The code he has (and your code) will not enable/disable jscroll based on window size.

Comment: You're right.. Guess I sort of misread the question. I updated my answer.

Comment: OP, if this worked. Please mark it as the correct answer so that others with the same or similar issues can use this as a reference to solve their issue.

Comment: I've used this code and even when I resize the window to less than 602px the code still runs. Sorry for the late reply, my battery died.

Comment: nope this is refusing to fire at all now. this is what I get in the console:  

TypeError: $(...).jscroll is not a function

Comment: You have included the successfully included jQuery and the jscroll plugin?

Comment: yes they are included, the only change I made was to change .scroll to .sectionTitle and #container to #mainArea (ie the css stuff in my page)