# Disable certain Javascript on devices

Tags: javascript, mobile, media-queries

I'm building a website and I'm using media queries to make the website responsive for mobile devices. On the desktop version of my website, I'm using the following Javascript to make 2 divs fade in/out once 100px have been scrolled down.

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (y > 100) {
            $('#firstHeadingLeft, #firstHeadingRight').fadeIn(3000);
        } else {
            $('#firstHeadingLeft, #firstHeadingRight').fadeOut();
        }

    });
```

Now the problem is, I don't want this javascript to be active on my mobile device, I want the 2 divs to be always present. I done some searching and found this

[How to disable JavaScript in media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659338/how-to-disable-javascript-in-media-query)

One of the suggestions was to add an event listener using this code

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
if(window.innerWidth > 568){
    ...execute script
} 
});
```

However because I'm not fluent in javascript I'm unsure how to correctly wrap my code into the event listener code.

If someone could give me a hand that would be appreciated! -- Thank you!

Comment: Just execute the code with the `resize` event (like you have) and the `onload` event as well. You can do that by calling a function. You already almost have it :)

Comment: Try using `screen.width` instead of `window.innerWidth`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work but I have no way to test it. Tell me what happens :)

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
   disableScript();
});

window.addEventListener('load',function(){
   disableScript();
});

function disableScript(){
    if(screen.width > 568){
      //...execute script
    } 
}
```

Comment: @user3599852 If it worked for you, please upvote and accept as best answer :) (please read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Wait.. I just tested it on my ipad. It's not working. The Javascript is still being loaded and is fading my Div's in and out.

Comment: I think it is because window.innerWidth on an ipad higher than 568

Comment: Try using an alert to find out. (I don't have a mobile device to test this).

Comment: Yup! Changing it to `screen.width` fixed it! - Thank you!

Comment: @user3599852 Thank you :) Merry Christmas.