# Load javascript only for min-width

Tags: javascript

I want to load a specific javascript only when min-width is > 1000 px.
Therefore I wanted to use this code which was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659338/how-to-disable-javascript-in-media-query):

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    if(window.innerWidth > 568){
        ...execute script
    }
});
```

Somehow this doesn't work. Here is my full code block:

```
         var t = (0, s.qs)(".js-twitter-feed");
         window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
             if(window.innerWidth > 1000){
         if ("undefined" != typeof twitterFeed && t) {
             t.classList.remove("u-hide");
             var r = document.createElement("div");
             r.innerHTML = '<a class="twitter-timeline" data-height="500" href="https://twitter.com/'.concat(twitterFeed, '">Tweets by ').concat(twitterFeed, "</a>"), t.appendChild(r), (0, o.loadScript)("https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js")
         }
             }
         });
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Don't do this. Use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: Perhaps [Testing media queries programmatically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Testing_media_queries) is a bit closer to where you want to focus your research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more performant way would be to use the [`window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) method to get a MediaQueryList and attach an eventListener to that.

Here's an example of how you can do that (the callback will be executed when the condition is met on page-load or when you resize the screen from below 300px to 300px or above):

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const callBack = () => console.log('do stuff');
  const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 300px)');
  
  if (mediaQuery.matches) callBack();
  
  mediaQuery.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
      if (event.matches) callBack();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works as expected but the only issue is that it doesn't work on page load, only after the window width has been changed. How can I add that feature as well?

Comment: @Peleke To achieve that you could wrap the code in an event-listener for the `DOMContentLoaded` event, and in the handler for that, check if the condition is met. I updated my answer to give you an example.